# Convert a list of strings to a list of integers

Tags: haskell

I have a list:

```
ls = ["1000", "2000", "4000", "8000"]
```

I want to convert the following list to a list of strings like the following:

```
ls = [1000, 2000, 4000, 8000]
```

I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
let val = (read ls :: Integer)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That will not work since you here use `read` for a *list* of strings. You should work with [**`map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map) to apply a function to all elements of a list:

```
let val = map read ls :: [Integer]
```

Answer (score 3):

To apply a function to *each member* of a *list*, the function [*`map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`*](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=map) is used, which creates the list of results of said applications.

So then you need to write

```
> let val = (map read ls :: [Integer])

> val
[1000,2000,4000,8000]
it :: [Integer]
```